# Getting 2 same fields in the same time

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I've 3 tables below. (sample)(mySql script)

### customer

- cust_id
- cust_name
- user_id
- user_id_2

### user

- user_id
- em_id

### employee

- em_id
- em_name

How can I call the `em_name` field for `user_id`, and `em_name` field for `user_id_2` by crossing `user` table in the same time with *join*??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT  q1.* ,
        q2.em_name AS 'em_name_2'
FROM    (SELECT c.cust_id ,
                c.cust_name ,
                c.user_id ,
                c.user_id_2 ,
                e.em_name
         FROM   dbo.customer AS c
                INNER JOIN dbo.[user] AS u ON c.user_id = u.user_id
                INNER JOIN dbo.employee AS e ON u.em_id = e.em_id
        ) q1
       CROSS JOIN 
       ( SELECT   e.em_id ,
                  e.em_name
         FROM     dbo.customer AS c
                INNER JOIN dbo.[user] AS u ON c.user_id_2 = u.user_id
                INNER JOIN dbo.employee AS e ON u.em_id = e.em_id
    ) q2
```

Comment: But I want the view like this:

cust_id, cust_name, user_id, user_id_2, em_name, em_name_2

Comment: Hello Prashant, the result is multiple. I wish I can upload the screenshot view to display you, but it need more than 10 reputations. --"